# How to fix 'unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'' error in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working with a dataset whose data I manipulated a bit with Pandas. I have no idea why I keep getting this 'unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'' error when I try to plot my data with Pandas.

Here is a picture of my work so far. The very last cell is where I keep getting this error. Can someone explain to me why this is happening? I see that s.values.dtypes gives me an array within an array, and I think that is the problem. But how do I go about fixing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.ndarray` can contain any type of element, e.g. `int`, `float`, `string` etc. Check the type an do a conversion if neccessary.

Comment: what do you mean? when i put in s.dtypes, i get it as as numpy.ndarray which is an unhashable object.